# Show that if $\mathbb{P}(X_{k}\neq 0\ \text{i.o.})=0$, then $\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$ converges almost surely.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

By i.o., I mean the infinity often. As asked in the title, I am working on the statement below:

> Let $X_{k}$ be mutually independent random variable and set $S_{n}:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$, show that if $\mathbb{P}(X_{k}\neq 0\ \text{i.o.})=0$, then $S_{n}$ converges a.s.

My idea is to use $\mathbb{P}(X_{k}\neq 0\ \text{i.o.})=0$ which may imply $$\mathbb{P}(|X_{k}|>\epsilon\ \text{i.o.})=0,\ \text{for all}
\ \epsilon>0.$$

Therefore, $X_{k}\rightarrow 0$ a.s. But this will give us $n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}\rightarrow 0\ \text{a.s}$

How could I prove $S_{n}$ converges a.s.?

Thank you!

Comment: What is a _necessary_ condition for a series $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_k$ to diverge?

Comment: @Daniel Fischer the limit of $a_{k}$ when $k$ goes to infinity is not $0$?

Comment: That's a sufficient, but not necessary condition, consider the harmonic series. The condition I'm after is closely related to the premise of the exercise.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer then I think you are implying the negation of the definition of a series to converge?

Comment: Think about the set $\{ k : a_k \neq 0\}$.

Comment: I feel like my solution is to simple so I’m probably missing something, but doesn’t $\mathbb{P}(X_k \neq 0 i.o.) = 0$ mean that you almost never have infinitely many nonzero terms, meaning that with probability 1, there are only finitely many nonzero terms, and all the S_n after the last nonzero term are the same thing so it converges?

Comment: @Robo300 You're not missing anything, that's what I was going for.

Comment: @Robo300 yes you guys are right..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A:=\{X_k=0\text{ ev.}\}$. By the stated assumption, $\mathsf{P}(A)=1$. For each $\omega\in A$ there exists $N_{\omega}\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $X_k(\omega)=0$ for all $k\ge N_{\omega}$ which means that $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n(\omega)=\sum_{k=1}^{N_{\omega}}X_k(\omega)$.